# Login script for an application

Tags: php, security

I am currently developing a login script for my application. The login will use SSL and all required resources will be served through this. It is not protecting anything like a bank however I would like to know what is right and wrong especially for learning purposes

I would love some feedback on my class that I have developed. I have been reading various sources on the net and a lot seems to be contradictory. I would love to know if there is anything else I can do with regard to this code and also the login process as a whole

Areas I feel need improvement:

- Use something stronger than sha1 for storing passwords.
- Maintaining login - currently it times out after 20 minutes.

```
class User extends Model{

private $logLocation; 
private $loginLog;


public function __construct(){
    $this->logLocation = 'system/logs/';
    $this->loginLog = "logins";
}

/**
*
* Add User
* @param    array   $data An array of data that will get added to User table.
*/
public function add($data){
    $db = Database::getInstance();

    $salt =  substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)),0,3);

    $query = 'INSERT INTO user(  user_id, user_username, user_password, user_salt, user_forename, user_lastname, user_email, user_attempts)
        VALUES( :user_id, :user_username, sha1(:user_password), :user_salt, :user_forename, :user_lastname, :user_email, 0)';
    $args = array(
        ':user_id' => $data['user_id'],
        ':user_username' => $data['user_username'],
        ':user_password' => $data['user_password'].$salt,
        ':user_salt' => $salt,
        ':user_forename' => $data['user_forename'],
        ':user_lastname' => $data['user_lastname'],
        ':user_email' => $data['user_email']);
    $db->query($query, $args);

    SessionRegistry::instance()->addFeedback('user Saved Successfully');
    return true;
}

public function getUserId($username){
    $db = Database::getInstance();
    //Check to see if the username exists
    $query = "SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_username = :username LIMIT 1";
    $results = $db->query($query, array(':username' => $username));
    return $results[0]['user_id'];
}

public function getUsername($userId){
    $db = Database::getInstance();
    //Check to see if the username exists
    $query = "SELECT user_username FROM user WHERE user_username = :username LIMIT 1";
    $results = $db->query($query, array(':username' => $username));
    return $results[0]['user_username'];
}

/**
 * 
 * Checks login details against that in the database
 * @param string $username
 * @param string $password
 */
public function checkLogin($username, $password){
    $db = Database::getInstance();
    //Check to see if the username exists
    $query = "SELECT user_salt, user_password, user_attempts FROM user WHERE user_username = :username LIMIT 1";
    $results = $db->query($query, array(':username' => $username));

    //No results return false
    if(count($results) < 1){
        $this->logLoginAttempt($username, 'Incorrect Username');
        return false;
    }

    //Check to see if the user is blocked
    if((int)$results[0]['user_attempts'] >= 3){
        $this->logLoginAttempt($username, 'Blocked User Login');
        return false;
    }

    //Check to see if the passwords match 
    if(sha1($password.$results[0]['user_salt']) == $results[0]['user_password']){
        $this->setLogin($username);
        return true;
    }
    else{
        //Incorrect Password
        $this->logLoginAttempt($username,  'Incorrect Password');
        $this->failedLoginIncrement($username);
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * 
 * Increments the failed login attempt for a user. 
 * 3 Strikes and they get locked out.
 * @param string $username
 */
private function failedLoginIncrement($username){
    $db = Database::getInstance();          
    //Update the IP address of the user from where they last logged in
    $query = 'UPDATE user SET user_attempts = user_attempts + 1 WHERE user_username = :username';
    $db->query($query, array(':username' => $username));

    //Check to see if the user has reached 3 strikes if so block them.
    $query = 'SELECT user_attempts FROM user WHERE user_username = :username LIMIT 1';
    $results = $db->query($query, array(':username' => $username));

    if($results[0]['user_attempts'] >= 3){
        //We need to block the user
        $query = 'UPDATE user SET user_blocked = 1 WHERE user_username = :username';
        $db->query($query, array(':username' => $username));
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * 
 * Logs a failed login attempt to a log file so these can be monitored
 * @param string $username 
 * @param string $reason
 */
private function logLoginAttempt($username, $reason){
    $fh = fopen($this->logLocation.$this->loginLog, 'a+') or die("can't open file");
    $logLine = date('d/m/Y h:i') . ' Login Attempt: ' . $username . ' Failure Reason: ' . $reason . " IP: " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "\n";
    fwrite($fh, $logLine);
    fclose($fh);
    return true;
}

/**
 * 
 * Sets the login data in the session. Also logs IP and resets the failed attempts.
 * @param string $username
 */
private function setLogin($username){           
    $db = Database::getInstance();          
    //Update the IP address of the user from where they last logged in
    $query = 'UPDATE user SET user_ip = :ip, user_attempts = 0 WHERE user_username = :username';
    $db->query($query, array(':username' => $username, ':ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));

    ini_set("session.use_only_cookies", TRUE);  //Forces the session to be stored only in cookies and not passed over a URI.
    ini_set("session.use_trans_sid", FALSE);    //Stop leaking session IDs onto the URI before browser can check to see if cookies are enabled.
    ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime", 1200);    //Time out after 20mins

    //Now add the session vars to set the user to logged in.
    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id(true); //Regenerate the session Id deleting old session files.
    $_SESSION['valid'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['userid'] = sha1($this->getUserId($_POST['username'] . "SALTHERE"));
}

/**
 * 
 * Checks to see if a user is currently logged in.
 */
public function loggedIn(){
    if($_SESSION['valid']){
        return true;
    }   
    else{
        return false;
    }       
}   

/**
 * 
 * Logs a current user out by destroying the session
 */
public function logout(){
    // Unset all of the session variables.
    $_SESSION = array();

    // If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
    // Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
    if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
        $params = session_get_cookie_params();
        setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
            $params["path"], $params["domain"],
            $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
        );
    }           
    // Finally, destroy the session.
    session_destroy();
}
}
```

I then use this class like so:

```
require_once('User.php');
$user = new User();
$loggedIn = $user->checkLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
if($loggedIn){
  //redirect to member area
}
else{
  //show login screen
}
```

Then on a page where I need to check if a user is logged in

```
require_once('User.php');
$user = new User();
if(!$user->loggedIn()){
  //redirect to login page
}
```

Comment: take care of sql injection: mysql_real_escape_string(form[data])

Comment: Thanks Rahul but I am using the PDO library to escape the data. Sorry I should of mentioned that in the Post as it is not apparent.

Comment: Looks like a good effort. A simple thing I'd suggest is check if your select query actually returns anything before trying to access the array: ` $results[0]['user_username'];`. Depending on your error_reporting level you will notice warnings on this.

Comment: Ahh yes Fanis very good point. Little things like that add more polish to the code. I will go back through and add some of the details.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/1151912 for some nice blowfish crypt function wrappers.  Not that the latest sha isn't okay, though.

Answer (score 2):

Like Fanis said in his comment, you might want to put error checking on both your `getUserId()` and `getUsername()`.

Good code overall (except maybe the singleton for your database object), few minor things like replacing `rand()` with [`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php). If you're worried about the security, you could check out [`crypt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) too.

Although getting user IP's is never 100% reliable you shoulud to look into using something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785931/most-reliable-way-to-get-ip-address-of-users-using-php) function for getting the IP of a user.

Comment: A thanks for the tips Stoosh. I know singleton isn't really a good pattern for the DB however I was more concentrating on the security side of things.

Comment: +1 for crypt, in my research blowfish crypt is the way to go for passwords, it's a slow hash that also allows you to store the salted + hashed password in a single field because the salt and the hash become a single entity, so that when you need the salt, the first bit of the hash acts as the salt, and they're never in different places from each-other.